Can the solutions of the two IVPs below be exactly the same?
Without actually solving them, would you say the solutions are the same? why?
y'' + 2y' + 10y = 0, y(0) = 0,  y'(0) = 1
y'' + 2y' + 10y = δ(t),  y(0) = 0, y'(0) = 0

Please use MathJax Formatting

"Same" in what regard?

There's a problem with #2: solutions to $y'' + 2 y' + 10 y = \delta(t)$ are not differentiable at $t=0$, and the one-sided limits of $y'(t)$ as $t \to 0$ from the left and right are different.  So is $y'(0) = 0$ supposed to refer to the limit as $t \to 0+$ or $t \to 0-$ or neither?
I suspect you mean $\lim_{t \to 0-} y'(t) = 0$.  Then the solutions to #1 and #2 will agree for $t \ge 0$.  But they certainly won't agree for $t < 0$.
